# Ensure that a view's IBOutlets have been instantiated

Tags: ios, swift, xib

I have a view which subclasses `UIView`:

```
class MyView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
    //..
}
```

The `IBOutlet`s are specified in a `nib`. I also instantiate `MyView` from the `nib`.

If `MyView` has a view controller, I would use `viewDidLoad` to determine when `myLabel` and `myButton` are instantiated. However, this is not the case here, as `MyView` is instantiated directly from a `nib`.

What should I do to determine when the two `IBOutlet`s are instantiated in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you're looking for is [`awakeFromNib()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1402907-awakefromnib#):

> The nib-loading infrastructure sends an awakeFromNib message to each object recreated from a nib archive, but only after all the objects in the archive have been loaded and initialized. When an object receives an awakeFromNib message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and action connections already established.

Implement `awakeFromNib()` in your `MyView` class, and it will be called when that view's outlets are connected.

Answer (score 3):

If you create it from nib, like this

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myXib" owner:self options:nil]
```

outlets will be initiated right after this line.